# Executing jquery within rails haml partials returned via jquery ajax through $q

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript, haml, angularjs

So I am writing an Angular Frontend for a pre-existing Rails Application. I understand that using $q is at best an intermediate step before converting the back end to serve a REST Api directly to ngResource through JSON, but unfortunately for the time being there is too much logic residing in various Ruby locations to easily rewrite everything into a purely Angular format.

The question is, how do I correctly instantiate and handle ng attributes in the returned partials. The below is a sanitized version of the code.

```
  Company.Controller.TypeAccordionController = (scope, http, element, q, typeJQueryService) ->

    scope.getTheDamnType = (id) ->
      typeJQueryService.multipart(id).then (response)->
        angular.element('.datePicker').datepicker()


   Company.Controller.TypeAccordionController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$element',      '$q','typeJQuery']
```

The returned HAML is being correctly displayed on the page and the datepicker is being instantiated successfully. The returned HAML contains the following:

```
 = ff.check_box :completed, :class => "field sale_#{sale.price}", :disabled => sale.completed?
```

Through the following service:

```
 Company.MyModule.factory 'TypeJQuery', ($q, $rootScope) ->
   multipart: (element) ->
     deferred = $q.defer()
     $.get "..." + element, (data) ->
       $rootScope.$apply ->
         deferred.resolve data
     deferred.promise
```

With the following Javascript being defined in a directive:

```
 Company.Directive.DatePickerDirective = ->
   restrict: 'C'
   controller: Company.Controller.TypeAccordionController
   link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
     $(".type-form input[type='checkbox']").click (e)->
          $checkbox = $(e.target)
          $date = $checkbox.parent('.checkbox').siblings(".target").find('.actually_completed_on_date')
          if $checkbox.is(':checked')
              if $date.val() == undefined || $date.val().length == 0
                  $date.val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-M-yy", new Date()))
              else
                  $date.val("")

   Company.MyModule.directive 'datePicker', Company.Directive.DatePickerDirective
```

Please note that before wrapping Angular around this, the javascript used to live directly in the asset pipeline, and used to run just fine.